# Which optimization technique I need to get started with to study Evolutionary Algorithms?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

I am starting the graduate course names "[Evolutionary Algorithms](http://eres.elka.pw.edu.pl/eres_en/wwersje_en$.startup?Z_ID_PRZEDMIOTU=EEVAL)".

Which optimization technique I need to get started with to study Evolutionary Algorithms?

Is it Mathematical optimization, or, any other type of optimization?

[Here, there are some types listed:](http://www.neos-guide.org/content/optimization-tree-alphabetical)

Comment: Pretty broad question. EAs are often used for discrete optimization problems, for which there are dozens of non-evolutionary approaches, both heuristic and exact. Some of these other approaches are fairly general-purpose and some are specific to certain problems.

Comment: Your question seems unclear. Evolutionary Algorithms *is* an optimization technique -- not something which requires non-EA optimization techniques as a prerequisite. What, exactly, are you looking for? Problems that EA can solve?

Comment: @JohnColeman, I am just trying to get an idea about my course beforehand so that I find less difficulty in understanding lectures. As you can see my syllabus starts with the discussion of `Optimization`, I was trying to get started with it. But, I don't know where to start. Researching through the Internet, I found that there are various kinds of optimizations. That is why I was asking people which Optimization would be most appropriate to get started with if I am going to study EA. http://eres.elka.pw.edu.pl/eres_en/wwersje_en$.startup?Z_ID_PRZEDMIOTU=EEVAL

Comment: You could read up on the Traveling Salesman Problem or the Knapsack Problem if you want to get a feel for the sorts of problems for which EA is often used. These are examples of combinatorial optimization problems. The Wikipedia article (and its links)  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization ) is well written. Another thing you could do -- read a book about biological evolution, maybe "Why Evolution is True" by Jerry Coyne for a quick overview (with a bit of anti-creationist polemics thrown in). The more you understand evolution the easier EAs are to understand.

Comment: @JohnColeman, Is the youtube link i provided useful or waste of time? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biwjg9tpOvM&list=PLVzYythIWXGMj4Wzoy67VPqb9PNRkIeJU

Comment: I would say waste of time for evolutionary algorithms (although knowledge is never really a waste of time).

Comment: @JohnColeman, Thank you very much multiplied by Infinity....... :-)